# Center block element in element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to center a block element (the WordPress caption box, including the image) but it won't work. I've tried:

```
.imagecenter {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

But it just won't work. I've also tried `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` but that won't work either. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? This is what the W3C documentation says I should do.

It looks like this in the HTML (to clarify):

```
<div id="content">
........post here......
<div class="wpcaption imagecenter" style="width:225px">
<img src="blah" />
Blah.
</div>
.........post here......
</div>
```

I have no control over the width of the element. It's set by the user. The user wants the div to be centered. It's not working. I've looked over documentation but it still won't work.

EDIT: I HAVE ALREADY TRIED MARGIN-LEFT: AUTO AND MARGIN-RIGHT: AUTO. IT DOESN'T WORK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, to position a div in the center, the technique is to make both the left and right margins auto and then give the div a width:

```
.centerDiv
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: XXX px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give it a width less than that of its parent.

```
.parent    { }
.imgCenter { width:320px!important; margin:auto; }

<div class="parent">
  <img src="foobar.jpg" class="imgCenter" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the width of the child; it's set inline. This is a WordPress theme. The parent should be already defined, as it's the container the content of the posts are in.

Comment: Brandon, you have to give the item you want centered an explicit width. That is how your margin:auto figures out what the margins should be.

Comment: I am. All the solutions you are giving I already know. The width is inlined in the html (as in <div style="width: 200px"> because it changes).

Comment: Add !important within your css.

Comment: If 200px is less than the parent width, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The width is set by the user through the WordPress write-post interface. I have no control over it. I just want it centered. I'm surprised there's no easy way to do this; I don't want to align=center things. I want to do it the CSS way. It's not working.

Comment: If there is an explicit width given, margin:auto will handle the centering...unless the width is equal-to or greater than the parent-width.

Comment: I don't know. Post a link to your page and we can help.

Comment: I can't. It's a WordPress theme, and I don't have the time to put up a test site yet.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution might be to set `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: auto` and `text-align: center` (for the caption text) on all child elements of your containing element:

```
.imagecenter *{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This means you won't have to explicitly set the width of your containing element, but has the drawback that your caption text will have a 100% width, which might look wierd.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those of who find this on Google, I found another answer:

Just give these attributes to your wrapper element and the contents will be center aligned.

```
width: 1024px; 
margin-left: auto;
/* I have used 1024px since I set the minimum resolution requirements for my website as 1024 x 768 */
```