# Display the image in the center of the page

Tags: css

I have a image -- a loading image.

I want that image to be displayed in the center on the page. 
How can I do that?

The code I wrote is :

```
img.loading
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

How can i make this image always be displayed in the center of the page?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to center vertically.  Can you confirm this?  Also, is your image going to be a fixed height?

Comment: possible solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207525/center-block-element-in-element/1207625#1207625](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207525/center-block-element-in-element/1207625#1207625)

Comment: try this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224399/display-the-image-in-the-center-of-the-page/15375386#15375386

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found this: [How to Center an Image Perfectly in CSS](http://labs.chemist2dio.com/how-to-center-an-image-perfectly-in-css.php), might help.

```
#img
{
    position:absolute;
    width:592px; /*image width */
    height:512px; /*image height */
    left:50%; 
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-296px; /*image width/2 */
    margin-top:-256px; /*image height/2 */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center#block)

```
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}

<IMG class="displayed" src="..." alt="...">
```

Comment: This will center the image horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: The link covers that, but it's not ideal. "CSS level 2 doesn't have a property for centering things vertically. There will probably be one in CSS level 3."

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `background: url(center_image) no-repeat center;`

---

**working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DT4hL/